# after OnPost values of variables reset to null in razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-pages

I wanted to add simple functionality to like on my page (that only displays data).

I've page with methods in PageModel behind (this is only example, becouse my page is soo more complicated):

```
(..)getting DB context and stuff
public string bookName {get;set;}
public string someVariable1 {get;set;}
public List<string> _bookTags {get;set;}
public int LikeCounter {get;set;}

public void OnGet(){
      someVariable1 = (from u in _context.table
                       where something==something
                       select u.x);
          _bookTags= (from u in _context.bookTags
                       where something==something
                       select u.y).ToList();
      LikeCounter = (from u in _context.likes
                       where u.book==bookName 
                       select u).Count();
}

public void OnPost(){
      likes newLike = new likes();
      newLike.userName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Split("\\")[1];
      newLike.book = bookName;
      _context.likes.add(newLike);
      _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Page looks like this:

```
(..)
<div class="col-lg-4">
        <form method="post">
            <button class="btn btn-reddit" type="submit">LikeThisBook</button>
        </form>
        Current likes: @Model.LikeCounter 
</div>
(..)
@foreach(string x in Model._bookTags){
        <div class="border">
          @x
        </div>
}
(..)
```

so the problem is when I display page - everything works, but when I click "LikeThisBook" - OnPost method fires, adding the like for this book with userName in it... then page display error:

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
```

and in stacktrace:

```
SomeProjectName.Pages.SomeBookStore.Pages_SomeBookStore_ShowBook.ExecuteAsync() in ShowBook.cshtml
@foreach(string x in Model._bookTags){    <- this is colored red
```

So it looks like that every variable that was filled in "OnGet" method is now null...

please help :)

Comment: The reason for this, is that the page is missing all the stuff you are doing in OnGet(). You should add a RedirectToPage in the end of OnPost()

Comment: but this will trigger page to reload? I don't want to reload page like this but after click save this like and then update counter on page without reload (just like facebook/twitter)

Comment: You should read about post-redirect-get (PRG), also called redirect after post. If user presses F5, the page will be resubmitted. Facebook/Twitter are using javascript-based libraries for this kind of functionality.

Comment: Hi @Aru,If my answer helped you,could you please accept as answer?It could also help others find the solution at once.Refer to:[How to accept as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).If still has problems,please follow up.

Comment: Yes, that is good answer, but finally I'm tring to keep it simple and finally I user PRG model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you do not want to reload the page and want to update the counter.The common way is using ajax.

Here is a working demo:

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <form method="post">
        <input name="bookName" />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-reddit" onclick="Add()">LikeThisBook</button>
    </form>
    Current likes: <label>@Model.LikeCounter</label>   @*add this*@
</div>
@foreach (string x in Model._bookTags)
{
    <div class="border">
        @x
    </div>
}
@section Scripts
{ 
    <script>
        function Add() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("label").html(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Fail to add");
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly RazorProj3_1Context _context;

    public IndexModel(RazorProj3_1Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
       
    }
    [BindProperty]
    public string bookName { get; set; }
    public string someVariable1 { get; set; }
    public List<string> _bookTags { get; set; }
    public int LikeCounter { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        someVariable1 = (from u in _context.table
                         where u.Id == 1
                         select u.x).FirstOrDefault();
        _bookTags = (from u in _context.bookTags
                     select u.y).ToList();
        LikeCounter = (from u in _context.likes
                           //where u.book == bookName
                       select u).Count();
    }

    public ActionResult OnPost()
    {
        like newLike = new like();
        newLike.book = bookName;
        _context.likes.Add(newLike);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        LikeCounter = (from u in _context.likes
                           //where u.book == bookName
                       select u).Count();
        return new JsonResult(LikeCounter);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
```

My testing models:

```
public class likes
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string book { get; set; }
}
public class BookTag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string y { get; set; }
}
public class Table
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string x { get; set; }
}
```

Result:
[image]